# WPF - Datagrid filter by Name with textBox

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, datagrid

I'm using this code to filter my dataGrid with a textBox, it works fine for filtering by the Id, but if I changed it to filter by the Name ( i just change the "Id" in the query with "Name"), it doesn't work, something like "Column name "Entered text" is invalid. This same error occurs when the query is set for Id and you enter a letter, apparently it only works with numbers.

Here is the code:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
            try {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\Sione\Documents\AcademiaSQLDB.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30; User Instance = True");
                con.Open();

                string query = "select * from instrutor";

                if (textBox.Text != "") // Note: txt_Search is the TextBox..
                {
                    query += " where Nome =" + textBox.Text;
                }
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("instrutor");
                adp.Fill(dt);
                instrutorDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                adp.Update(dt);

                con.Close();

            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

So how can I filter the dataGrid by the Name? Filtering by the Id works perfect thought but it's not very user friendly. Thanks

Comment: Maybe a typo issue : `query += " where Nome =" + textBox.Text;` Nome or Name?

Comment: Nome is Name in Portuguese, so i just translated for you guys understanding it beter,but "Nome" is right ^^

Comment: Which `Exception` do you have?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Columm name 'here goes the letter you entered in the textBox ' is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your filter with `'`
So the line :

```
query += " where Nome =" + textBox.Text;
```

become

```
query += " where Nome ='" + textBox.Text + "'";
```

Note that this is a quick fix, and you need to consider @Dennis answer

Comment: This Worked Great @ZwoRmi , Big Thanks =D

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string concatenation to build SQL queries, this will lead to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use parameters instead:

```
private SqlCommand CreateCommand(SqlConnection connection)
{
   return new SqlCommand("select * from instrutor", connection);
}

private SqlCommand CreateCommand(SqlConnection connection, TextBox textBox)
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("select * from instrutor where Nome = @nome",  
        connection);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", textBox.text);
    return command;
}

private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    using (var command = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text) ? 
        CreateCommand(conn, textBox) : CreateCommand(conn))
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Also note, that: 1) `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter` implement `IDisposable` and should be disposed (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx)); 2) there's no need to execute `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Comment: I get your point, i just don't understand how to use this in the TextChanged void there, since i'm new in this.